# Spotify progress bar clone exactly

Tags: css

```css
input {
  height: 4px;
  appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  background-color: #5e5e5e;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /* display: none; */
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}

input[type="range"]:hover {
  background: green;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" />
```

I've been working on cloning Spotify web page(https://open.spotify.com), but stuck in making the progress bar for the music player. I don't know how to style the lower part for the range input. Can some pros give me advices?. This is my first question on da Stack :)

Comment: Could you add your HTML and CSS in a snippet so we can run and have a better look at what you've done so far?

Comment: HTML/CSS in snippet is done. Can u guy show me how to fix that or maybe we can think about a new way to do it

Answer (score 0):

It may look like an `<input type="range">` tag, but it's achieved with just `div` tags.

For example you can have one `div` which could be styled as the progress background, and another `div` as a child of the first one which acts as the fill of the progress. And the fill percentage is being transformed with some JavaSciprt to match the actual progress of the audio - you can change it with css attributes - e.g. `width` or `transform`. The progress thumb (the little white circle) is just another `div` element which appears on hover.

The functionallity is achieved with JavaScript mainly but I think it's not in the scope of your question.